# Print value from inside an object

Tags: php, json

I have really have troubles trying to work out why this is not working, and it seems like it should be easy, but just cannot seem to get it.

All I am looking to do is grab the sku field (which is VBP-01 below).

```html
{
    "variants": [
        {
            "id": 2314578,
            "created_at": "2014-07-29T07:22:18.921Z",
            "updated_at": "2015-05-21T15:42:42.136Z",
            "product_id": 1188647,
            "default_ledger_account_id": null,
            "buy_price": "124.0",
            "committed_stock": "0",
            "incoming_stock": "3",
            "composite": false,
            "description": null,
            "is_online": false,
            "keep_selling": false,
            "last_cost_price": "124.0",
            "manage_stock": true,
            "max_online": null,
            "moving_average_cost": "124",
            "name": "Lanparte battery pinch VBP-01",
            "online_ordering": false,
            "opt1": null,
            "opt2": null,
            "opt3": null,
            "position": 1,
            "product_name": "Lanparte V-Mount Battery Pinch",
            "product_status": "active",
            "product_type": null,
            "retail_price": "0.0",
            "sellable": true,
            "sku": "VBP-01",
            "status": "active",
            "stock_on_hand": "1",
            "supplier_code": "VBP-01",
            "taxable": true,
            "upc": null,
            "weight": null,
            "wholesale_price": "0.0",
            "image_ids": [],
            "variant_prices": [
                {
                    "price_list_id": "buy",
                    "value": "124.0"
                },
                {
                    "price_list_id": "retail",
                    "value": "0.0"
                },
                {
                    "price_list_id": "wholesale",
                    "value": "0.0"
                }
            ],
            "locations": [
                {
                    "location_id": 16377,
                    "stock_on_hand": "1",
                    "committed": null,
                    "incoming": "3",
                    "bin_location": null,
                    "reorder_point": 3
                }
            ],
            "prices": {
                "buy": "124.0",
                "retail": "0.0",
                "wholesale": "0.0"
            },
            "stock_levels": {
                "16377": "1.0"
            },
            "committed_stock_levels": {},
            "incoming_stock_levels": {
                "16377": "3.0"
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "total": 1
    }
}
```

Currently I using the following code with no luck

```html
$url = "https://api.tradegecko.com/variants?sku=VBP-01";
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

$json = json_decode($data);

print $json->{'variant'}->{'sku'};
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me why some integer variables have their value in quotes while others don't.

Comment: Not sure on that one, but I can only assume that those values do not exist for this product. Only null, false and true are the not in quotes

Comment: variants in an array. There could be any number of those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just

```
echo $json->{'variants'}[0]->{'sku'};
```

In a loop

```
foreach ($json->variants as $variants) {
    echo $variants->sku;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Could you possibly explain why?

Comment: "variants" was just an array